# mySQL Type for 8000 Words

Tags: php, mysql

I have 8000 words I would like to toss into a field of my mySQL database. However it isn't allowing me to dump it in. I have the data type set at longtext. Is there something I can do to make sure that 8000 words can get stored into a field?

Thanks!

Comment: What is it doing when you "dump it in" (I'm assuming you mean INSERT there)? 
Longtext fields have a storage maximum. My first guess is that you're exceeding the maximum space, but it's not likely since storage max is like several gigs... 
Why don't you tell us what the error code is when you try an insert? In php mysql_errno() and mysql_error() will provide you with usually what is very adequate information to directly solve your problem. 
My first suggestion is to start with that, and if you're still confused come back and let us know.

Comment: I'm not getting any error it's just not inserting the text into the field. When I use text that is around 1000 words it inserts the text. Its just when I get to a certain level.

Comment: Okay try mysql_info() and see what that brings back to you... Though it's interesting that it's failing to insert AND not giving you an error. You did try actually running mysql_errno() and printing the value, right? Just to be clear.

Comment: are you seeing the results in phpmyadmin? try, to echo the result or use var_dump

Answer (score 3):

According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-type-overview.html), you can store up to 4Gb in a `LONGTEXT` field - depending on some other circumstances as well - so unless your words are really long (I mean really really long!), the length is not the problem.

How are you sending the text to the database? There might be some other factors involved like post size, server timeouts, etc.

Comment: I'm just posting the text to a handler and then a mySQL insert.

Comment: The MySQL server might not be allowing the query because it's too big. The `max_allowed_packet` server parameter will need to be large enough to accommodate.

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly works for me,

```
<?php
    $longestWord = "";

    for($i=1; $i<=8000; $i++){
       $longestWord .= $i . " longestWordInTheWorldEver ";
    }

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO checkTable SET words = '$longestWord'");

?>
```